# How to make an array that has a variable as the size?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, input, size

For example:

```
int size;
cout << "Enter array size" <<endl;
cin >> size;
int myarray[size];
```

I want the user to be able to enter the size of the array, but I keep getting an error message saying I'm not using a constant variable. When ever I search for an answer to this question, I get information about how to store a variable in an array (not what I'm looking for).

Comment: use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: use `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`.

Answer (score 4):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the *C++* standard, although they are part of the *C99* standard and several compilers support them as an extension in *C++* including [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla), Visual Studio being one of the [notable exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx) though.

The obvious *C++* solution would be to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or possibly [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) although that means you have to worry about delete'ing the memory as well.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can simply use **`std::vector`**, in your case a `std::vector<int>`.

You then need to include the `<vector>`  header.

```
using std::vector;
int size;
cout << "Enter array size ";
cin >> size;
vector<int> myarray(size);
```

A `std::vector` takes care of managing memory for you, and it also has a handy **`push_back`** method to add an item at the end, expanding the array as necessary.

This means that you *do not have to* decide up-front on a specific size, but can simply add more items.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handles this in C++03 and C++11 is to use a managed dynamic array type such as `std::vector`:

```
int size;
std::cout << "Enter array size" << std::endl;
std::cin >> size;
std::vector<int> myarray;
myarray.resize(size);
```

`std::vector<int>` behaves a lot like a raw array of `int`s.  You can use `[3]` to access elements, as an example.

This is superior to managing the memory yourself, as ever experienced programmers lose track of memory.

There are proposals to add dynamically sized arrays to C++1y (the next iteration of C++) or later in an extension in a way that is *somewhat* compatible with C99 (an important difference is that `sizeof(variable length array)` in C99 is runtime evaluated, but not in C++).  There are also proposals to add `std::dynarray`, which is a slightly less heavyweight `std::vector` style class with some possibility of automatic storage optimization.  None of this is really needed to solve your problem.

Comment: I figured I would do one thing on each line.  The cost (at run time) is very modest, and I figured it would be clearer for someone whose first interaction with `std::vector` is this post to do each step explicitly.